# Using Stepwise Regression To Determine number of predictor variables to use in a forecasting model

Tags: forecasting, stepwise-regression

Is it appropriate to use predictor variables that are statistically significant when considered in stepwise-regression for a forecasting model?

Comment: You might get conflicting answers to this..

Comment: Members here have different opinions.

Comment: @MichaelChernick What about your opinion?

Comment: I favor trying stepwise methods as well as all subsets as long as you use a good criterion like AIC or BIC that penalize too many parameters which could lead to overfitting.  Often it is hard to look at all subsets.  Frank Harrell has his own book on regression and has a very different viewpoint.